# BigQuery , SQL : extract time diff from two timestamps

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a table like this:

```
event_timestamp                               SESSION_ID    
2021-01-24 15:22:33.761011 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 15:22:33.761011 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 15:22:53.335013 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 15:24:53.700444 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 15:25:05.362517 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 15:25:05.362517 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 15:25:48.949679 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 15:25:48.949679 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 15:27:47.543331 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 15:27:47.543331 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 15:28:22.442896 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 15:28:22.442896 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 15:34:41.572305 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 16:37:28.988887 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6    
2021-01-24 16:37:28.988887 UTC  0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
```

I need to calculate avg session time:

```
with cte as (
SELECT
timestamp_micros(event_timestamp) as timestamp,
min(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp)) over (partition by  SESSION_ID) as min_time,
max(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp)) over (partition by  SESSION_ID) as max_time,
SESSION_ID
FROM 'table'
)
select 
timestamp
round(avg (timestamp_diff(min_time,max_time,second)) over (partition by c.SESSION_ID)/60,2) as AVG_session_time,
SESSION_ID
```

Output:

```
event_timestamp                     AVG_session_time    SESSION_ID
2021-01-24 15:22:33.761011 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 15:22:33.761011 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 15:22:53.335013 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 15:24:53.700444 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 15:25:05.362517 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 15:25:05.362517 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 15:25:48.949679 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 15:25:48.949679 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 15:27:47.543331 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 15:27:47.543331 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 15:28:22.442896 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 15:28:22.442896 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 15:34:41.572305 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 16:37:28.988887 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
2021-01-24 16:37:28.988887 UTC        74.92         0046aa0e-5035-4b2d-a6de-77a47949cdf6
```

but 74.92 is not a time difference, because this 74 minutes and 92% of 60 seconds
so I need to get an answer like 0.92*60/100 = 74:55
I can not extract a percentage of seconds and calculate seconds, because there is a problem with conversion and extraction between text and number ......
Is there another way to get a result in the form of time (minutes and seconds) ???

Thanks )

Comment: You aren't taking the average of minutes but seconds. 
74.92 is not "74 minutes and 92% of 60 seconds"
it is 74 seconds and 92% of a 1 second, or 920 milliseconds.
This is then 1 minute and 14.92 seconds. Not the answer you asked for but I hope it helps.

Comment: But if a function in seconds: timestamp_diff(min_time,max_time,second), does it not return a result in "seconds"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select average_session_duration,
    format(
        '%i day %i hour %i minute %i second', 
        unix_date(date(timestamp_seconds(average_session_duration))), 
        extract(hour from time(timestamp_seconds(average_session_duration))), 
        extract(minute from time(timestamp_seconds(average_session_duration))), 
        extract(second from time(timestamp_seconds(average_session_duration)))
    ) as average_duration_as_long_string,
    regexp_replace(
        cast(time(timestamp_seconds(average_session_duration)) as string), 
        r'^\d\d', 
        cast(extract(hour from time(timestamp_seconds(average_session_duration))) + 24 * unix_date(date(timestamp_seconds(average_session_duration))) as string)
    ) as average_duration_as_short_string
from (
    select cast(avg(session_duration) as int64) as average_session_duration from (
        select 
            timestamp_diff(max(event_timestamp), min(event_timestamp), second) session_duration
        from `project.dataset.table`
        group by SESSION_ID
    )
)
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response
In your solution, the result obtained is the result of all the sessions. If for example, I have a lot of sessions then there will always be one result for everyone. Maybe there's a way to do it per session?